# Finding the max value of an array, and get the program to give me the number of the array

Tags: java, arrays

So im working on an assignment and i am almost done, but i can't find a solution that works for me. So i have these arrays, 1 that asks for a name, and 2 that asks for work hours and hourly rate. With the hourly rate and work hours, i then create another array that gives the total salary.

So i need to print out the highest salary and the name of that person who has them.

So i'm looking for a way that gives me the slot number that max value is in, so i can use System.out.Println("a[maxslotnr] + " has the highest salary which are " "d[maxslotnr])

Here is the code

```
public class MaxLaun {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    StdOut.print("what is the amount of employees ");
    int amount = StdIn.readInt();
    String[] a = new String[number];
    int[] b = new int[number];
    int[] c = new int[number];
    int[] d = new int[number];



    for (int i=0; i <  amount; i++) {
       StdOut.print("Name of employee");
       String name = StdIn.readString();
       a[i]  = name;
       StdOut.print("hourly rate");
       int rate = StdIn.readInt();
       b[i] = rate;
       StdOut.print("amount of worktime");
       int time = StdIn.readInt();
       c[i] = time;
    }

    for (int j=0; j < number; j++)
    d[j]= (b[j] * c[j]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Note : you are create the arrays with `number` and not `amount`, is it a typo ? (Same in the second for loop) (Why a second loop ? Do the b * c in the first one)

Answer (score 1):

When asking in SO you should use English as much as possible. Even in your code.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
    int maxValue = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < fjoldi; j++) {
        if (d[j] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = d[j];
            pos = j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey and thank's for the quick reply! i edited the text for you to english so you can understand it better :P and yes i think you have it right. I'll go try it out.

Comment: you could remove the maxValue and use the index directly ;)

Comment: As @AxelH said it is possible to ditch the maxValue with 
`int pos = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < fjoldi; j++) {
            if (d[j] > d[pos]) {
                pos = j;
            }
        }`
But that increases complexity for a new coder. I wanted the code simple.